# Xcode not able to find project file

Tags: ios, xcode

In my Xcode project there are other projects linked but somehow its not able to read the sub project.

[image]

As you can see `MobiResourceManager.xcodeproj` is shown in red. And thus the classes which uses headers inside it gives error. But I am not able to understand why its not able to show the project. Sometimes it doesn't show `MobiResourceManager.xcodeproj` in red but even then the classes using its header gives error of `HeaderName.h` not found.

The problem that I am facing is happening only in my system. I tried cleaning, deleting-installing Xcode, cloning the repository again but nothing works.

All the project file shown in the screen shot are sub project inside one main project.

Answer (score 1):

Probably that red file was removed or moved somewhere else. Open Finder, locate the missing `xcodeproj`, then remove this one in Xcode and drag&drop the located one. If that red `xcodeproj` is inside your repository (what I suspect) then do not select to copy it to the destination.

If you cannot locate that red file, it means it is not added to the repository. For example, it could mean that you need to install it with git submodules or another way - depends on the project configuration.

Comment: When using my xcode I right click and try to see the project location for the red one, I do get the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the workspace? if yes then please open that file not xcode project file

Comment: Actually the ones shown in screenshot, are all sub project under one main project.